# Text indexing mode for Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I've seen various tag and index capabilities for Emacs, but they seem to be for code tagging and indexing. What I'd like is the ability to mark/highlight a word or phrase in any (text) Emacs buffer, do C-i, and have that word "saved off" to some index buffer. What would really be nice would be to save the "position" of the indexed term (word or phrase). So, if you're in org-mode

```
* level 1
** level 2
*** under level 2-1
*** under level 2-2
    - This is a comment that talks about sushi for vegans.
```

I could get *sushi* saved off along with its 1.1.2.1 position in the org buffer. Anything like that available?

Comment: Sounds like bookmarks (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks).

Comment: Yes, bookmarks are probably what you want. But FWIW, the tagging you refer to (TAG files) is not just for code tagging/indexing. It will work for anything - any kind of definition, for example. But you will need to write a program that produces the TAG file. :-( Similarly, Imenu works for any kind of definition, but you need to come up with the regexps or functions that can identify the definitions.